# When is cmakes add_custom_command POST_BUILD being triggered?

Tags: cmake, cmake-custom-command

Lets consider that I have registered a custom command for a target:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${target_name} POST_BUILD
                   COMMAND cmake -E copy_if_different ${file_path} ${dest_file}
                   COMMENT "exporting ${file_path} to ${dest_file}"
                   VERBATIM)
```

What I am struggling to find out is when the command is actually being run.
Always after the target has been checked like this ?

```
[ 10%] Built target libzmq
```

Even if *'nothing has to be done'* ?

Or just in case that for the target something had to be done ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3aadd_custom_command):

```
The command becomes part of the target and will only execute when the
target itself is built. If the target is already built, the command will
not execute.
```

Comment: Ahem, right, I take the blame ;). Seems my reading of the documentation wasn't thorough enough ...